# Tab content that is scrollable

Tags: java, user-interface, tabs, scroll

I am new to Java GUI and I am trying to create some tabs that have panels of images inside them.  I would like to fix the size of the tab and have it scrollable so the users can see all the content in the tab.  Is there a way to make the content inside the tab scrollable?

A short example would be of great help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a JTabbedPane, and add a Panel containing a JScrollPane, which contains your Panels of images.  That may sound confusing, but it is just a hierarchy:

JFrame
|
JTabbedPane
|
JPanel
|
JScrollPane
|
JPanel
|
images

You might initialize your JScrollPanel as follows:

```
JScrollPane imageScroller = new JScrollPane(myImagePanel); //the panel containing the images
JPanel scrollPanel = new JPanel(); //make the panel containing the scroller
scrollPanel.add(imageScroller); //add the scroller to the panel
myTabbedPane.add(scrollPanel); //make a tab out of it
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried that and added some other things and it worked. I guess my mistake was that I wasn't making my content scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the content inside the tab scrollable?

Use a JScrollPane.  See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) in the Java Tutorial for details.